# Ubuntu install from ISO always kicks back to "Ubuntu installer main menu"

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, server

I'm trying to install Ubuntu server from ISO, on a system that doesn't have networking connectivity to the Internet, but I'm not able to get past a certain point.

Initially, the process proceeds normally, it seems to partition things correctly and installs the base system.

However, when I get to the "Configure the package manager" stage in the "Ubuntu installer main menu", and I hit "enter", I see a dialog that says "Configuring apt" with a progress bar, and then it goes right back to the "Ubuntu installer menu".

The same thing happens no matter what other option I select (e.g., Install the GRUB boot loader on a hard disk, Finish the installation, Abort the installation): a dialog that says "Configuring apt" with a progress bar appears, and then it kicks back to the installer menu.

I'm at a loss to how to troubleshoot this, since I don't see any error message during this process.

I've tried both Ubuntu Server 12.04 and Ubuntu Server 12.10, same result.

Comment: Got the same problem with 13.10.

Comment: Difference is, I have network connectivity. I have a couple of identical machines, I installed it on one without problems, on the next two I run into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comments, I had the same problem. Turned out that the reason for this was a faulty network cable, after switching it out the installer went through.